# Django REST Framework: How do I change the color of top strip in Browsable UI

Tags: css, django, django-rest-framework

There is a few pixels wide strip at the very top of the Browsable UI. The default color for it is `#A30000`. It's defined in a stylesheet bootstrap-tweaks.css for the element `navbar-inner`. I'd like to change the color of that strip, but I'm not sure how to do it.

What should I put in my api.html to modify the color? Thanks.

Comment: Open bootstrap-tweaks.css, do a ctrl+f for "navbar-inner" find the color "#A30000" and change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I added to my api.html:

```
{% block style %}

{{ block.super }}
<style>
.navbar .navbar-inner {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2C2C2C;
    border-color: ****MY_COLOR_HERE**** -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    border-right: medium none;
    border-style: solid none none;
    border-width: 5px medium medium;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>

{% endblock %}
```